# What is a Java library for outputting text formatted for printing?

Tags: java, swing, printing, formatting, reporting

I'm working on a legacy Java program.  I need to print out data reports in **pure ASCII**.

Some of the data is in the form of tables which is tricky because I need to **wrap columns** when they are too long for the width of the page.  Also, for tables that span multiple pages I need to reprint the table headers.

I also need to export tables in **CSV**.

In addition, I need to **report tree**-like data structures in human-readable ASCII.

I've looked around for **libraries**, but haven't found anything that meets my needs, does anyone know of any good plain text layout libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks promising as a light-weight exporter.  However, hand-rolling a solution with help from some string manipulation libraries may be the final solution.

http://code.google.com/p/data-exporter/

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to write your data to a Java in-memory relational database such as Apache Derby or h2database and then use a standard Java reporting tool such as Jasper Reports ( http://www.jasperforge.org or http://www.jaspersoft.com/ ) that has word-wrapping, page headers, CSV export and lots of other reporting features you may or may not want.

Comment: Looks like a good product, but a database is too heavy for my needs.  I guess I may end up hand-rolling a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Apache FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/index.html)?

Comment: Thanks, but I really need a library for pure text, basically String manipulations.

Comment: Yup, I thought FOP may be kind of heavy for your task :)